# How many timers can one utilize from ATSAM4s2A?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, atmel, cortex-m4

I am getting introduced to Atmel ARM MCUs and I have several dilemmas regarding their documentation. According to the official Farnell documentation of [ATSAM4S2A](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1794215.pdf). the MCU supports only three timers:

[image]

However when I visited the official website of Microchip, the [datashee](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATSAM4S2A)t of the same MCU mentions 6 timers, which three of them are for "internal use":

[image]

I tried digging through ATSAM documentation and I wasn't able to find what exactly internal use means. Can I repurpose these three timers for my own use, or maybe they are unavailable and used only internally by the system?

Maybe someone could explain what is the exact internal use and what benefit does one have from it, such that these three timers are worth mentioning in the datasheet?

Comment: On the newer datasheet, in the block diagrams for the various parts, notice that Timer Counter 1 has no external signals.  So it seems you cannot use Timer Counter 1 to input (input capture) or output (PWM) any external signals.  But perhaps you can use it internally (timer mode).

Comment: @kkrambo That makes a lot more sense. I guess internal use meant something different than what I comprehended :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 timer counter blocks, but you can have different GPIO's piped into those blocks (depending on the pin count of the device).

> A Timer Counter (TC) module includes three identical TC channels. The
> number of implemented TC modules is device-specific

pg 851 Source: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1794215.pdf

I suspect that the additional 3 timers could be used for interrupts, but not GPIO's, ether that or processor hardware uses them.

This block diagram shows what is available (3 hardware timers, with multiple GPIOs) to the GPIO's and what timer inputs you can 'pipe in' to the timer counter blocks:

[image]
Source: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1794215.pdf